# Can TFS build 2010 and 2013 exist on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

We've a new build machine with "TFS build 2013" installed, point to VSO.
The dev team want to run old scripts against "TFS 2010" but it seems TFS Build 2013 is not compatible with TFS 2010 (so says the error when a Build controller is create point to the TFS 2010), so we want to install TFS Build 2010 on the same machine.
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only one version of Team Build can be installed on a build server at a time. You'll need to uninstall Team Build 2013 and install Team Build 2010.

You *can* configure Team Build 2010 (with all the latest [service packs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20506) and [forward compatibility patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)) to connect to VSO and TFS 2010 at the same time though.

Comment: Thanks that's we'l have to create a second machine. On the TFS Build 2010 and VSO, I'm not so sure, I think I tried it a couple of weeks ago and failed.

Comment: I've just tried again to connect to VSO with TFS Build 2010 and got the error "Cannot register Team Foundation Build Service: Upgrade your build   server to a new version and try again".

Comment: No. I'm install sp1 now http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20506 but I dont see the "Forward Compatibility pack" where can I get it?

Comment: you can get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082 Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR